# "Multi-distributive" operations on sets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, hyperoperation

As you can remember from Algebra courses, if $A$ is a set, and exist functions $\oplus , \odot: A \to A$ such that $(A,\oplus,\odot)$ is a ring, then such ring has a distributive property such that $$\forall \, a,b,c \in A \quad \; \, a \, \odot \, (b\, \oplus c) = (a \odot b) \; \oplus \; (a \oplus c )  $$ Or commonly said "$\odot$ distributes **over** $\oplus$". 
My question is, ¿Is there any ring with distinct operations such that "$\oplus$ distributes **over** $\odot$"? Or more specifically:
$$\forall \, a,b,c \in A \quad \; \, a \, \oplus \, (b\, \odot c) = (a \oplus b) \; \odot \; (a \oplus c )  $$
Notice that what I'm looking for is a ring with a pair of operations such that "$\odot$ distributes **over** $\oplus$" and "$\oplus$ distributes **over** $\odot$" simultaneously.
It's clear that at least in rings like $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ or even $\mathbb{Z_2}$ this doesn't happen with usual product and sum. 
 I'm wondering if this can even exist, a kind of "bi-distributivity" (clearly, if this comes out as true, my dream question could be: if you have $n$ distinct operations in a set, could you have a ${n \choose 2}$-distributivity for an operation ? .
 Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you want a set with two operations that are a ring, and **in addition** sum also distributes over the sum? Or do you want a set with two operations, each of which distributes over the other, but that do not necessarily give you a ring?

Comment: I want a Ring with two operations, each of which distributes over the other. (I made a mistake translating my question, I'm sorry and thanks for clarifying)

Comment: There was an answer here about lattices in logic, Seems like that might interest you.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: @DannyOfek: Lattices with more than one element cannot give you a ring: both operations are idempotent, so neither operation can give you an abelian group structure on a set with more than one element.

Comment: I know... he just seems curios I know i enjoy this algebras and they show what you have to give up to get what he wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $(R,+,\cdot,0,1) $ be a ring in which $'+'$ distributes $'\cdot '$ we show that $R=0$. (In the comment section Arturo shows this is true for rings without a multiplicative unit)

1. for any 3 elements $a,b,c\in R$ we have:
   $$a+bc=(a+b)(a+c)=a^2+ac+ba+bc$$
   $$\implies (1):a=a^2+ac+ba$$
2. if a=b=c in (1) we get:
   $$ 3a^2=a$$
3. therefore if a=c in (1) we get:
   $$3a^2=a=2a^2+ba\implies a^2=ba$$
4. in (3) put a=1 and get:
   $$\forall b\in R:1=b$$

Comment: And if your ring does not have a unity?

Comment: Interesting question, did you just delete your answer? I think it might interest the author of the question

Comment: No, it’s easy to fix: from $a^2=ba$ for all $b$, take $b=0$ to get $a^2=0$ for all $a$. Then this gives $ab=0$ for all $a,b$. Then $a=a+bc=(a+b)(a+c) = 0$.

Comment: (No, I didn’t put the other answer; I pointed out a mistake in it, though)

Comment: Thanks Arturo ill add it

Comment: Then , If a ring (A, + , $\cdot$) has two operations such that each one distributes over the other, then the set A is a singleton ?

Comment: if + and $\cdot$ are the operations, yes.

Comment: Understandable, have a nice day  & thanks a lot.